# How to find out if a promo code for an in-app purchase has been redeemed?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, promotions

I had generated 100 codes for an in-app purchase from the Promotions section on the Google Play Console and have started sharing with some new users.

However, the Play Console just mentions that 10 out of 100 promo codes have been redeemed but does not reveal which those 10 promo codes are. I want to know so that I can follow up with those users who have not redeemed yet.

I even looked at the purchase data that I receive inside the app when I fetch active purchased items via the billing library. This is the following data it contains -

```
{"packageName":"com.app","productId":"product_sku","purchaseTime":1579983348800,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"1234___abcd"}
```

No promo code here either.

So, how can I find out if a particular promo code has been redeemed or not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: Ofcourse it is about programming! An api or some way to find out if the a promo code has been used or not which would be used as a check in the CODE in the backend or the app so that someone doesn't receive a used up promo code OR so that an admin can check if a promo code has been used or not so that it can be shared to some other user. This would happen automatically in a function or CODE. I would deem that being "about programming"!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually.

1. Log in to Google Play on your computer with an account that already has the purchase.
2. Go to https://play.google.com/store?code
3. Enter the codes, one by one. It will tell you if it's already been redeemed. If it hasn't been redeemed, it shouldn't be when you try because you already own it.

Comment: The page is not available for me anymore. https://play.google.com/store?code  Does anyone know about how to check promo code now?